# How can we find the annual growth rate (database size) for a historical database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-schema

I have a historical DB in SQL Server that is 7 to 8 years old. How can I find at what rate it has grown annually since 2007 using a SQL query or steps in SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Look at your regularly scheduled FULL backup sizes in the MSDB [Backup History and Header tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188653.aspx).

In particular, [backupset](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299.aspx) and [backupfile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190274.aspx) may be of interest.

Alternately, look at the actual size of the actual full backup files (not differential or T-log, just the fulls).  You can use [RESTORE HEADERONLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx) to get further information.